# contar palabras en especifico en swift

Tags: swift4

Buenas tardes estoy intentando contar solo por ejemplo .hilarious dentro de un arreglo pero no me sale lo eh intentado muchas veces pero no me sale.... eh visto y averiguado en internet pero nada... Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por favor añade tu código como texto, después selecciónalo y dale clic al ícono de `{}`